# How to get a Maximum DateTime in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

Am new for android development here is my doubt i have saved the datetime field as text in sqlite how to get the maximum datetime among these records how can i achieve this i came to know that it can be achieved through Max() query i tried but am not getting the result here let me post what i have tried so far:

Here is the Sqlite Query:

```
 public String DateTime(){
        String str="";
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomerModel.CustomerTable , new String [] {"MAX(" + CustomerModel.Customer_LastMofiedFlag +")"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { // to move the cursor to first record
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_LastMofiedFlag);
            str = cursor.getString(index);
        }  mcontext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(DB_Timetracker, null);
        return str;
    }
```

Is it possible to get the maximum datetime in text format am saving the datetime format in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss how can i achieve this!!

Comment: You should not store date as text. because date in text is inaccurate and easily lead to issues. The best way is to store it as a `long` using `System.currentTimeMillis();` that is a epoch time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). After you have a number, it's easy to use a `max/min` query in SQLlite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Comment: does sqlite supports long format

Comment: byte, int or long matters not. It's all the same to the many-faced god. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html (`INTEGER` in SQLlite can be any size integer

Comment: now how to query the long format

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to save it in long format?

Comment: use INTEGER - it is 8-bit and will be enough

Comment: while converting string to long am getting wrong  value

Comment: Could you show me what do you try to convert, how and what you get?